# Define function of a list from a function of its elements (SetDelayed)

Tags: function-construction

Consider the following:

```
 n = 5;
 vars = Array[x, n];
 a = 3 x[1] - 2 x[2]^2 + x[5]
```

How can I define a function mapping `vars` (i.e. a function of `{x[1],x[2],...,x[n]}`) to `a`? The following works but cannot be easily made general:

```
f[vars_] := a /. x[1] -> vars[[1]] /. x[2] -> vars[[2]] /. x[5] -> vars[[5]]
```

Comment: Why not just `f[vars_] := a`?

Comment: @klgr This does not work, it does not substitute the definition of `vars` (there's no `vars` in the RHS).

Comment: maybe you meant to use a symbol different from `x` in the definition of `vars`. As is, there is no need to use replacements like `x[1] -> vars[[1]]` because `vars[[1]]` _is_ `x[1]`, no?

Comment: @kglr: Let me reformulate: I'd like to have a function "`f[{x[1]_, x[2]_, x[3]_, x[4]_, x[5]_}] = 3x[1] - 2x[2]^2 + x[5]`" but without what to express the (incorrect) `{x[1]_,x[2]_,...`. With `f[vars_] := a`, `f[{3, 2, 1, 0, 0}]` returns `3 x[1] - 2 x[2]^2 + x[5]` while I expect the value `5`. Is it more clear now?

Comment: I see. please the answer I posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n = 5;
var = Array[c, n]
a = 3 x[1] - 2 x[2]^2 + x[5]

ClearAll[f1]

f1[vars_] := a /.  x[i_] :> vars[[i]]

f1[var]
```

> `3 c[1] - 2 c[2]^2 + c[5]`

```
f1[{3, 2, 1, 0, 0}]
```

> 1

```
f1[{3, 1, 1, 0, 1}]
```

> 8

```
f1[{3, 1, 100, 200, 1, 10, 1, 50}]
```

> 8

Comment: Would it be possible to not use `SetDelayed` in the definition of `f1` (i.e. something like  `f1[vars_] = a /.  x[i_] :> vars[[i]]`)?

Comment: @anderstood, `SetDelayed` is needed here;  try `ClearAll[f1, vars]; f1[vars_] = a /. x[i_] :> vars[[i]]`

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I meant: how could I define `f1` with `=` instead of `:=`?

Comment: @anderstood, maybe cheating as in `f1[vars_] = Quiet[a /. x[i_] :> vars[[i]]]`? But you will get in trouble if `vars` is already defined.