# Define function of a list from a function of its elements (Set)

Tags: function-construction, assignment

I asked a similar question there: [Define function of a list from a function of its elements (SetDelayed)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138657/define-function-of-a-list-from-a-function-of-its-elements).
This one is different because I'd like to use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`, and it makes a big difference.

Let's say I have a long expression which depends on `x[1]`, `x[2]`, ..., for example here simply `3x[1]+x[5]`. I want to define a function based on  this expression, but of course I don't want to rewrite it manually as:

```
 f[{x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_,x5_}] = 3x1 + x5
```

Just to explain better, I'd looking for something like the incorrect

```
 expr = 3x[1] + x[5]
 f[Array[x_]] = expr
```

so that `f[{a,b,c,d,e}]` would return `3a + e`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html):

```
expr = 3 x[1] + x[5];

f[x_List] = expr /. x[i_] :> Indexed[x, i];

f[{a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> ```
> 3 a + e
> ```

Or [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
f2[x_List] = expr /. x[i_] :> Quiet[ x[[i]] ];

f2[{a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> ```
> 3 a + e
> ```

Comment: @anderstood Since you want that form there is no point to the `Block` construct I presented first; I therefore removed the extraneous parts of my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Why `RuleDelayed` instead of just `Rule`?

Comment: @Alan `:>` will protect against the case where `i` is assigned a value; `->` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
f[x_List]:= 3 x[[1]] + x[[5]]
```

Comment: You are using `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`, and you are not using `expr` directly (I don't want to retype `expr` which I supposed to be complicated).